# Toad format sql statement in one row

Tags: sql, format, toad

How can I change the formatter in toad or maybe sql developer to format my sql statements automatically in one row statement.

Here one Example:
This is my start which I wanna to format.

```
BEGIN
    db_package.drop_table ('test');
END;

CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    Column                     VARCHAR2 (1 CHAR)
);
...
```

This is my goal formatted statement.

```
BEGIN    db_package.drop_table ('test');END;
CREATE TABLE mytable(    Column                     VARCHAR2 (1 CHAR));
...
```

So I want to format the statements so that I get every statement in one row.

Comment: Why? It just makes the code less readable.

Comment: Putting it in code tags makes it easier to see at a glance what is code and what is your questions/comments about the code. But do you really want all those spaces in the finished code?

Comment: I need this format, because I want to reead each sql command per line and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

**TOAD FOR ORACLE**

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+F should help you

To format a statement Select the statement you want to select and click `»` on the Edit toolbar.

To format an entire script Click `»` on the Edit toolbar.

**Tip**:You can also right-click the script and select Formatting Tools |
Format Code.

To achieve the exact formatting you may need to play around with the 'Oracle Formatter Options'